# using sed to edit a url string in script

Tags: linux, string, bash, sed, edit

I need to edit these strings in a configuration file

```
<port>8189</port>
<service>127.0.0..1:8190</service>
<wan-access>localhost</wan-access>
```

I have tried

```
. variables.sh

cat config.sh |
  sed -i.bk \
  -e 's/\<^port\>\/'$port'/\<\/\port\>/'  \
  -e 's/\<^service\>\/'$url'/\<\/\service\>/' \
  -e 's/\<^wan-access\>\/'$url2'/\<\/\wan-access\>/' config.sh
```

In the script the variables are supplied by the variables.sh file. 
Out come should be

```
<port>8787</port>
<service>my.domain.com:8190</service>
<wan-access>my.realdomain.com</wan-access>
```

Comment: There's no need to escape the angle brackets.  I don't understand what you're trying to do with the `^` characters.  `^` represents the beginning of the input, so it will cause problems the way you're trying to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the trick:

```
port=8787
url="my.domain.com"
url2="my.realdomain.com"

sed -i.bk -Ee "s/(<port>)[0-9]+(<\/port)/\1${port}\2/" \
    -e "s/(<service>)[^:]*(:.*)/\1${url}\2/" \
    -e "s/localhost/${url2}/" config.sh
```

Output:

```
<port>8787</port>
<service>my.domain.com:8190</service>
<wan-access>my.realdomain.com</wan-access>
```

Regep Explanation:

```
s/          # The first substitution 
(<port>)    # Match the opening port tag (captured)
[0-9]+      # Match the port number (string of digits, at least one)
(<\/port)   # Match the closing port tag (captured, escaped forwardslash)
/           # Replace with 
\1          # The first capture group
${port}     # The new port number
\2          # The second capture group

s/          # The second substitution 
(<service>) # Match the opening service tag (captured)
[^:]*       # Match anything not a :
(:.*)       # Match everything from : (captured)
/           # Replace with
\1          # The first capture group
${url}      # The new url 
\2          # The second capture group

s/          # The third substitution
localhost   # Match the literal string
/           # Replace with
${url2}     # The other new url
```

*The tag matching perhaps doesn't need to be so verbose but it's certainly easier for a beginner to understand.*

**Edit:**

If you want to change the `<service>` port then try this:

```
-e "s/(<service>).*(<\/service)/\1${url}:${port}\2/"
```

Comment: First thanks for the code. It produced on the second line <service>my.domain.com:8787:8190</service>. Of course you can see this too many ports. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've had a years long habit of piping sed through sed. I like this use of the -e option.

Comment: See my edit, should solve your issues.. Here is a good place to learn, read questions, ask questions, try stuff out as well as online tutorials for `sed` and `regex`.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial suggestions. I will look more into the site. The code works fine now. And really thanks for the explaination.