# Edit multiple lines of a file locally and then rename multiple times- Linux

Tags: linux, sed, edit

I have a file with numerical values that need to be edited multiple times and saved as separate files.

e.g.

1. theta = 0.0 deg ---> theta = 30.0 deg
2. r = 1.0  ---> r= 4.0
3. put, molden, visual_1_0 ; ---> put, molden, visual_r_theta ;

Then the file needs to be saved as a a function of the edited value e.g. 
n2o_r_theta.inp

For editing I have tried

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..6}
do
 r = 1.0
 theta = i*15.0
 cat n2o.inp |
 sed -i.bk -Ee "s/(theta = )/\1${theta}\2/" \
     -e "s/(r = )/\1${r}\2/" \
     -e "s/(put, molden, )/\1visual_${r}_${theta};\2/" n2o_${r}_${theta}.inp
done
```

Giving me the following errors

1. editor.scr: line 5: r: command not found
2. editor.scr: line 6: theta: command not found
3. sed: -e expression #1, char 18: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS

Best case scenario is if this script could be 2 do loops over theta and r. I used [using sed to edit a url string in script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574397/using-sed-to-edit-a-url-string-in-script) as my main reference.

**End Result** - Allows me to lazily parallelize molpro scripts since it has wonky multidimensional implementation

```
LC_ALL=C

for j in {4..4}
do
for i in {1..6}
do
    r=$(echo "scale=1; $j/2.0" | bc -l)
    theta=$(echo "scale=1; $i * 15.0" | bc -l)
    sed "s/theta = 0.0/theta = $theta/;
         s/rnn = 1.0 ang/rnn = $r ang/;
         s/visual/visual_r_${r}_theta_${theta}/" < master.inp >n2o_r_${r}_theta_${theta}.inp
    molpro2010s n2o_${r}_${theta}.inp &
done
done
```

Comment: There should be no space between variable and value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something next:

```
LC_ALL=C
for i in {1..6}
do
    r=$(printf "%.1f" $i)
    theta=$(printf "%.1f" $(($i*15)) )
    sed "s/theta = 0.0/theta = $theta/;s/r = 1.0/r = $r/;s/visual_1_0/visual_r_theta/" < n2o.inp >n2o_${r}_${theta}.inp
done
```

You should don't have spaces between `=` in the assignment. Calculation (integer only) in `bash` can be done with `$(( expression ))` syntax.

The `printf` formats the number as floating point number with one decimal precision, and finally the 'LC_ALL=C' sets the locale to `C` - so, the `printf` prints decimal point and not a comma as in many international setting. (if you're has C or us and like, don't need the LC_ALL line).

The above script produces from the input file:

```
theta = 0.0 deg
r = 1.0
put, molden, visual_1_0 ;
```

the next 6 files

```
theta = 15.0 deg
r = 1.0
put, molden, visual_r_theta ;

theta = 30.0 deg
r = 2.0
put, molden, visual_r_theta ;

theta = 45.0 deg
r = 3.0
put, molden, visual_r_theta ;

theta = 60.0 deg
r = 4.0
put, molden, visual_r_theta ;

theta = 75.0 deg
r = 5.0
put, molden, visual_r_theta ;

theta = 90.0 deg
r = 6.0
put, molden, visual_r_theta ;
```

if you want the

```
put, molden, visual_r_theta ;
```

substituted with the values of `r` and `theta` use the next `sed` line:

```
sed "s/theta = 0.0/theta = $theta/;s/r = 1.0/r = $r/;s/visual_1_0/visual_${r}_${theta}/" < n2o.inp >n2o_${r}_${theta}.inp
```

will produce lines like:

```
put, molden, visual_4.0_60.0 ;
```

and finally, if you need floating point calculations, you should use the `bc` command like:

```
theta=$(echo "scale=1; $i * 12.5" | bc -l)
```

and so on...

Comment: I had just finished all the arithmetic when I looked back at this. Extremely helpful. Made my life much happier.